# Does the gitattributes file ensure consistency across platforms without setting core.autocrlf value

Tags: git, github, terminal

Does setting the EOL value in a .gitattributes file ensure Linux/Mac users fetch the code in LF and push the code in LF, and Windows users fetch the code in CRLF and push in LF? I am confused as to how git handles EOL simply by configuring the gitattributes file and not the core.autocrlf value.

Answer (score 1):

Git has a couple different settings that control how line endings work.

First, in the `.gitattributes` file, there's `text`.  If set, it means the file is text and subject to line ending conversion; if unset, the file is binary and not subject to line ending conversion; and if set to `auto`, it means that Git should guess based on the contents of the start of the file.  Usually Git guesses correctly, but since it doesn't read the entire file for performance reasons, it can sometimes guess wrong (very especially on PDFs).

Second, there's the `eol` attribute in the `.gitattributes` file.  If set to `crlf`, then the file has LF endings in the repository and CRLF endings in the working tree; if it's set to `lf`, then it has LF endings in both the repository and the working tree; and if it's unset, it has the defaults (outlined below).  Note that `eol` has no effect if `text` is not set, either explicitly or implicitly.

These are always acceptable options to use, and in fact, they are preferred.  Oftentimes, it doesn't matter what line endings are used in the working tree, and so `text` is set and `eol` is left unset.  However, for some types of files, it matters.  Shell files must always use an LF and Windows batch files must always use CRLF; otherwise, they simply don't work.  Thus, you will always want to specify an `eol` for those.

If `eol` is not specified, the default line ending for the working tree on the system is specified by the `core.eol` setting, which can be `lf`, `crlf`, or `native` (the default).

Now, in some cases, you didn't specify the `text` attribute.  In that case, its default values depends on `core.autocrlf`.  If that option is set to true, it's equivalent to defaulting to `text=auto` and `core.eol` to `crlf`.  If it's set to `input`, then no conversion is performed unless the `.gitattributes` says otherwise.  If you have users on Windows, this will almost certainly result in CRLF in the repository, which you probably do not want, since it leads to ugly `^M` markers on diffs and Git tools producing whitespace warnings.

If you're not sure what to do, just use `.gitattributes` for your project, which will always work correctly.  It is often enough to do `* text=auto`, although sometimes you'll want something different, as mentioned above.  That will result in the situation you want: where Unix users use LF in the repository and working tree and Windows users use LF in the repository and CRLF in the working tree, unless they've configured their line endings differently on their system (which is fine).